# How can I create desktop shortcut for a command

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to execute the following command by clicking an icon on desktop:

```
LANG=EN geany
```

I tried creating a Bash script however it just opened the file with Gedit, after double clicking. How can I create a shortcut and execute it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better for http://askubuntu.com/. Also, it may depend on which desktop environment you're using.

Comment: [check this out](http://askubuntu.com/questions/299052/how-to-execute-sh-script-from-a-desktop-shortcut) It may help you resolve your question

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
LANG=EN geany
```

Save it as a `whatever.sh`, make it executable, double click and let me know how it goes.

Comment: thank you for your answer. that is exactly what I tried. when I double click it opens the file with gedit. what am I doing wrong? I placed the file on desktop, could that be the problem? or must I place it somewhere in system folders.